# Can't make a spacer occupy the blank space between widgets when stretching a layout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've recently started with PyQt5 and am now trying to write an interface for an application.

I want to have a sidebar with different tools and essentially an I/O panel at the bottom of the window.

This I/O panel should contain only 2 `QPushButtons` - `Ok and Cancel`.

When I change the size of the application window, the right button (Ok) is supposed to stay in the bottom right-hand corner, while the left button (Cancel) - in the bottom left-hand corner, right next to (but not below) the sidebar. To achieve that, I've added a horizontal spacer between the buttons.

However, both buttons always remain in the bottom right-hand corner of the window. I've played with `QSizePolicy` parameters a bit, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The only way I've been able to get what I want was by setting the horizontal spacer width in the constructor at a non-zero value, but I'm not satisfied with this solution. What should I change in the code below to get what I want?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Sidebar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(maximumWidth = 200, minimumHeight = 50))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(maximumWidth = 200, minimumHeight = 50))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(maximumWidth = 200, minimumHeight = 50))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(maximumWidth = 200, minimumHeight = 50))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(maximumWidth = 200, minimumHeight = 50))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(maximumWidth = 200, minimumHeight = 50))
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(200, 0, QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setMaximumWidth(200)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

class IOPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Cancel", maximumWidth = 100, maximumHeight = 30), 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 30, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Maximum))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Ok", maximumWidth = 100, minimumHeight = 30), 0, Qt.AlignRight)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        panel = IOPanel()
        layout.addWidget(QWidget(), 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(panel, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

class Interface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(Sidebar(), 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addWidget(Canvas(), 0, Qt.AlignRight)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        interface = Interface()
        self.setCentralWidget(interface)
    
def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the layout to QGridLayout in your Interface widget. You can play around with number of rows and columns to suit your setup/goal.

```
....
class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        #panel = IOPanel() # Remove IOPanel from Canvas widget add it to Main Interface
        layout.addWidget(QWidget(), 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        #layout.addWidget(panel, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

class Interface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(Sidebar(), 0, 0, 4, 1)
        layout.addWidget(Canvas(), 0, 1, 3, 3)
        layout.addWidget(IOPanel(), 3, 1, 3, 3)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
```

Comment: Note that "playing around" with rows and columns won't change anything in this case, unless other widgets are going to be added to the inner cells *or* specific row/column sizes/stretches are set. Remember that the rows and columns in a grid layout have absolutely **no** size if there are no widgets occupying them (unless, as said, stretches or minimum sizes are explicitly set for them). The above code should be changed like this: `layout.addWidget(Sidebar(), 0, 0, 2, 1)` `layout.addWidget(Canvas(), 0, 1, 1, 1)` `layout.addWidget(IOPanel(), 1, 1, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the way the layouts are set, but due to the usage of the alignment argument for [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) (emphasis mine):

> The alignment is specified by alignment. The default alignment is 0, which means that **the widget fills the entire cell**.

This means that specifying an alignment will *not* make the widget fill the entire cell, but only its *preferred* size (what's returned by `sizeHint()`). Moreover, since you are already adding a spacer to the sidebar, and the buttons will be on bottom of the vertical layout of the canvas, specifying the alignment is unnecessary anyway.

So, the solution is simple: remove all unrequired arguments from `addWidget()` (including the stretch, which already defaults to 0):

```
class Interface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        layout.addWidget(Sidebar())
        layout.addWidget(Canvas())
```

Note that you might want to do the same for all `addWidget()` in `Canvas` too.

Other considerations:

- QPushButton already tries to expand as long as the layout on which it's added allows it; since you already set a maximum width for the panel, setting it also for the buttons is pointless;
- boxed layouts already provide convenience functions for spacers (`addStretch()` and `addSpacing()`), which internally create QSpacerItems on their own: you can use `layout.addStretch()` between the buttons of `IOPanel`;
- unless you need to set advanced aspects in the size policy, there's no use in creating a new object: you can directly use [`self.setSizePolicy(<horizontal policy>, <vertical policy>)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1) instead;
- multiple levels of widgets and their layouts increase the amount of margins between objects (that's why there is a lot of space around the IO buttons) unless margins are explicitly removed for *all* involved layouts; unless you go for a grid layout, consider using less container widgets and use *nested* layouts by using `addLayout()`; another option is to override QStyle's [`pixelMetric`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#pixelMetric) and return 0 for all `PM_Layout*Margin` metrics, but that would default *all* layout margins to 0 unless explicitly set;
- most of the size related code set for the panel is a bit boilerplate; consider using simpler concepts and avoiding unnecessary calls: remove the spacer item and add a stretch, use stylesheet `min-size` properties and properly implement `sizeHint()`; as you can see, the resulting code is much cleaner and easier to read:

```
class Sidebar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
        layout.addStretch()

        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Sidebar > QPushButton { min-height: 50; }
        ''')
        self.setMaximumWidth(200)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.maximumWidth(), super().sizeHint().height())
```